# D3 update bar chart - Can't bind new data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transition

Hello I'm new to d3 and I couldn't update the data in my bar chart.
I'm creating the bars using following code.

```
g.selectAll(".bar")
.data(data)
.enter().append("rect")
.attr("class", "bar")
.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter) + 1; })
.attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
.attr("width", x.bandwidth() - 1)
.attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.frequency); })
```

I was able to modify the data using hard coded values:

```
var bar = svg.selectAll(".bar");

bar.transition().duration(750).data(data).enter()
   .attr("y", function(d) { return 0; })
   .attr("height", function(d) { return Math.random()*100; });
```

How can i properly bind the new data?

Comment: Updating data means you have to redraw the graph. You will have to create a function which will redraw the graph. You can keep the code which depends on data in that function

Comment: Your question is not exactly clear. What do you want to know, how to rebind the data or how to set the selections? Meanwhile, have a look at this example in the S.O. Docs: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/d3.js/5749/update-pattern/20318/updating-the-data-a-basic-example-of-enter-update-and-exit-selections#t=201701241434416574182

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the snippet below for an example of updating the bar chart with new data programmatically and showing a transition animation in the process.

```js
var data = [{x:10, y:10, w:50, h:25},
            {x:10, y:40, w:150, h:25},
            {x:10, y:70, w:70, h:25}];

var g = d3.select("g");

// Bind initial data to empty selection, then use enter()
// to access the virtual selection from the data-join
// and subsequently append a rect for each virtual selection
g.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; })
    .attr("width", function(d) {return d.w; })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return d.h; });

var new_data = [{x:10, y:10, w:150, h:25},
                {x:10, y:40, w:50, h:25},
                {x:10, y:70, w:100, h:25}];

// Bind the new data to the rect objects. Since new_data
// is of the same size as number of rects, enter() and exit()
// selections from data-join will be empty and the rects
// with updated bound data are now available in the default
// update selection.
g.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(new_data) // grab the update selection by default
      .transition().duration(3000)
      .attr("width", function(d) { return d.w; }); // Update the attribute
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<svg width="400" height="400">
  <g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: thank you for your working code snippet! It helped me to understand.